# Access Jenkins model instances from Gradle

Tags: plugins, jenkins, gradle

I'd like to develop a Gradle plugin that performs some operations on the Jenkins model object.
(such as automatically fingerprinting the compile dependencies and the published ivy artifact)
Do you know if it is currently possible to retrieve the instances of Jenkins' AbstractBuild and other classes from a gradle plugin ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you'd achieve this with a Gradle plugin, as you need to be running inside the Jenkins JVM to access the model object.  You might find it easier to use the [REST API](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API) if it exposes the data you need.  Otherwise you'd need to attach to the Jenkins JVM process remotely.